# Mapcar in-place: destructively modify a list of lists

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, in-place

I have a list of lists: `(setq xs (list (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6) (list 7 8 9)))`. I want to remove a first element from each list to get `((2 3) (5 6) (8 9))`. It's easy to do it non-destructively: `(mapcar 'cdr xs)`. But I want mutate the original list. I tried:

```
(mapcar (lambda (x) (setf x (cdr x))) xs)
(mapcar (lambda (x) (pop x)) xs)
```

But it doesn't work. How to change each list of `xs` variable in-place, without creating any temporary lists, as efficiently as possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `MAP-INTO`:

```
CL-USER 16 > (let ((s (list (list 1 2 3)
                            (list 4 5 6)
                            (list 7 8 9))))
               (map-into s #'rest s))
((2 3) (5 6) (8 9))
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Rainer Joswig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27667244/596361)'s answer is correct, use [`map-into`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_map_in.htm). The link gives example implementation using [`loop`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm) macro. If you want to implement `map-into` from scratch, or you use Emacs Lisp, you can also do it using [`dotimes`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_dotime.htm). In Emacs Lisp `dotimes` is implemented in `subr.el` and doesn't require [CL package](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/index.html). This is `map-into` with 1 sequence to map into the result sequence:

```
(defun map-into (r f xs)
  (dotimes (i (min (length r) (length xs)) r)
    (setf (elt r i)
          (funcall f (elt xs i)))))
```

For version with variable amount of sequences we must sprinkle our code with `apply` and `mapcar`:

```
(defun map-into (r f &rest xss)
  (dotimes (i (apply 'min (length r) (mapcar 'length xss)) r)
    (setf (elt r i)
          (apply f (mapcar (lambda (s) (elt s i))
                           xss)))))
```

We see, however, that `elt` inside `dotimes` makes our algorithm work in O(n<sup>2</sup>). We can optimize it to work in O(n) by using [`mapl`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) (thanks [@Joshua Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1281433/joshua-taylor)).

```
(defun map-into (rs f xs)
  (mapl (lambda (r x) (setf (car r) (funcall f (car x)))) rs xs))

(defun map-into (rs f &rest xss)
  (mapl (lambda (r xs)
          (setf (car r)
                (apply f (car xs))))
        rs
        (apply 'mapcar 'list xss))) ;; transpose a list of lists
```

The reason [`setf`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_setf_.htm) doesn't work inside `mapcar` is that `setf` is a [complex macro](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/variables.html#assignment) that expands into expression that can manipulate the data it mutates. In a lambda scope inside `mapcar` it has access only to a variable, local to this lambda, not to the sequence passed to `mapcar` itself, so how should it know, where to put a modified value back? That's why `mapcar` code in the question returns modified list of lists but doesn't mutate it in-place. Just try `(macroexpand '(setf (elt xs 0) (funcall 'cdr (elt xs 0))))` and see for yourself.

Comment: Using `elt` to access the elements of the list like this is expensive.  It  makes the function in n<sup>2</sup> time instead of n.   It would be better to keep track of the tails of the list, so that you're always getting the first element.  You could use [**mapl**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) to do this efficiently.  E.g., to remove the first element from each of the lists, you could **(mapl (lambda (tail) (pop (first tail))) list)**.

Comment: See edit. Do the new functions work in O(n)? Also, is it possible to simplify variable-argument map-into?

Comment: The new functions are O(n), which is good.  I think you can simplify the second implementation of **map-into**, though.  E.g., see http://pastebin.com/W8tLkVBR.